# Passing vm arguments to java program in batch file

Tags: batch-file, memory, command, conditional-statements

I am trying to run a java program from a batch file and I need to pass arguments based on some condition. Based on condition number of arguments passed to java command differs. 
Below is the code what I tried.

```
@echo off
set vmargs1 = "-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=25"
set vmargs2 = "-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"

IF condition1 (
java %vmargs1% MyJavaClass
)
IF condition2 (
java %vmargs2% MyJavaClass
)
```

For condition1, I need to pass vmargs1 as virtual machine arguments to launch java program. And for condition2, I need to pass vmargs2 as virtual machine arguments for launching java program. 
   I am facing issue in setting value of vmargs1 and vmargs2. With above code, its not setting those values. 
And using %vmargs1% and %vmargs2% in calling java program is correct or is there any other way of doing it? If so please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the blanks on the set command and the double quotes.

```
set vmargs1=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=25
set vmargs2=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```